# $.AJAX .post() not working - Server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a View for an MVC5 app. This is an `Edit` View with multiple properties, several of which are related to other models. I have my main `INV_Assets` model and then several other tables for `Location, Manufacturer, Model, Status, Type, Vendor`, etc. On this `Edit` view, I'm displaying those particular properties as dropdown lists containing all values currently in those tables, along with a [CREATE NEW] button by each list.

When user selects the [CREATE NEW] button, I have a hidden form which appears and allows a user to enter a new value for the specific Table/DropDown. I've got everything working except the POST where I add the value to the Table and refresh the DropDown list.

Below is what I have put together for my first dropdown (the `Model` selection) -- everything is functioning up to the POST:

**INV_Assets.Edit View**:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Manufacturer:</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manufacturer_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Model_List, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Manufacturer_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">CREATE NEW</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**INV_Assets.Edit Script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Show() form to enter new Model.
            $('#createNewModel').click(function () {
                $('#createModelFormContainer').show();
            })

            // Submit new Model value and refresh dropdown
            $('#submitNewModel').click(function () {
                alert("New Function!"); // WORKING

                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                var url = form.attr('action');
                var data = { Text: form.find('input').first().val() };

                alert("Prior to Post"); // WORKING

                $.post(url, form.serialize(), function (data) {

                    alert("Begin POST!"); // NOT BEING REACHED!

                    $('#selectModel').append($('<option></option>').val(data.ID).text(data.Text));
                    form[0].reset();
                    $('#createModelFormContainer').hide();
                })
            });
        });
</script>
```

When my code hits the `$.post` something goes wrong. It was previously getting:

[image: Script1]

Since `post()` seemed to be the anonymous function, I assumed I did not have ajax installed. I then installed `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`, which now renders my error as: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://localhost:4545/INV_Assets`.

Any thoughts on this?

As best as I understand it, my submit should be posting to my below  `createNewModel()` method inside my `INV_AssetsController`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult createNewModel(INV_Models model)
    {
        model.created_date = DateTime.Now;
        model.created_by = System.Environment.UserName;
        model.modified_date = DateTime.Now;
        model.modified_by = System.Environment.UserName;

        if (ModelState.IsValid == false && model.Id == 0)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.INV_Models.Add(model);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return Json(new { ID = model.Id, Text = model.model_description });
    }
```

Assuming it is something to do with my routing, this is my current `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Anyone with more expertise able to see what I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**:

Using **wahwahwah**'s suggestion, I made the following modification to my script:

```
        $('#createNewModel').click(function () {
            $('#createModelFormContainer').show();
        })

        $('#submitNewModel').click(function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = { Text: form.find('input').first().val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("createNewModel", "INV_Assets")',
                data: data,
                success: function (resp) {
                    alert("SUCCESS!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }
            });
```

Going this route, my `createNewModel()` action is correctly called in the controller, but fails out at `db.SaveChangesAsync()`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult createNewModel(INV_Models model)
    {
        model.created_date = DateTime.Now;
        model.created_by = System.Environment.UserName;
        model.modified_date = DateTime.Now;
        model.modified_by = System.Environment.UserName;

        if (ModelState.IsValid == false && model.Id == 0)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.INV_Models.Add(model);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return Json(new { ID = model.Id, Text = model.model_description });
    }
```

The error is as follows:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

---

**EDIT2**:

Modified my troublesome code to be in a try/catch and then set a `Watch` on ex:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult createNewModel(INV_Models model)
    {

            model.created_date = DateTime.Now;
            model.created_by = System.Environment.UserName;
            model.modified_date = DateTime.Now;
            model.modified_by = System.Environment.UserName;

            // Set ID
            int lastModelId = db.INV_Models.Max(mdl => mdl.Id);
            model.Id = lastModelId+1;

            if (ModelState.IsValid == false && model.Id > 0)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.INV_Models.Add(model);
                    db.SaveChangesAsync();}
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                }
            }

            return Json(new { ID = model.Id, Text = model.model_description });  
    }
```

`ex` Details:

[image: DbEntityValidationErrorDetails]

Apparently the `description` I'm entering for the new Model is not being included in the new `Model` that is being saved?

---

**EDIT3**:

Below is my current script/controller action code. When I break inside the controller and type `?model.model_description` into the `Immediate Window`, it returns `null`.

Regarding my below alerts, the value in my `<input type="text" name="model_description" />` appears to not be correctly stored in the variable for use by JSON, and thus is not passed to the controller?

- `alert(test)`: `S2EFXrd3nXdWOIES5eBi4e_Fz3wrqCwP44hhQ7kj_foL3qkNv26OBgQoqHC-8BV8HKC6xdDEa7uCBnhOFPKL3AwIko99p-j_887qQgOXRPg1`
- `alert(data.model_description)`: `S2EFXrd3nXdWOIES5eBi4e_Fz3wrqCwP44hhQ7kj_foL3qkNv26OBgQoqHC-8BV8HKC6xdDEa7uCBnhOFPKL3AwIko99p-j_887qQgOXRPg1`
- `alert(jasonData.valueOf())`: `{"model_description":"S2EFXrd3nXdWOIES5eBi4e_Fz3wrqCwP44hhQ7kj_foL3qkNv26OBgQoqHC-8BV8HKC6xdDEa7uCBnhOFPKL3AwIko99p-j_887qQgOXRPg1"}`

**INPUT FORM**:

```
            <div id="createModelFormContainer" style="display:none">
                <form action="/createNewModel">
                    <input type="text" name="model_description" />
                    <input type="button" id="submitNewModel" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
```

**Script**:

```
        $('#submitNewModel').click(function () {

            var form = $(this).closest('form');

            var test = form.find('input').first().val();
            alert(test);

            var data = { model_description: form.find('input').first().val() };
            alert(data.model_description);

            //var data = { model_description: $("input[name = 'model_description']").text.toString() };

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(jsonData.valueOf());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("createNewModel", "INV_Assets")',
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (resp) {
                    alert("SUCCESS!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }
            });
```

Comment: did you check if whatever's running on port 4545 actually has a `/INV_assets` url? since it's an http request, you should be able to that exact same url directly in your browser and see what happens.

Comment: When I paste the URL directly I get `404 - A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'InventoryTracker.Controllers.INV_AssetsController'.` This is true, I have no `Index()` method in my `INV_AssetsController`. In my `post()` I'm attempting to go to `createNewModel()` action, with no idea why it is trying to access Index? After digging it seemed that my default routing might be forcing it to look for Index since it can't seem to find my `createNewModel()` action....?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that might help you troubleshoot your **View / jQuery:**

1. Make sure you are actually posting JSON
2. That you are retrieving a value when calling `form.find('input').first().val()'
3. You are posting to an accurate URL
4. That the JSON object you are posting has the same property naming conventions as the model in your controller

Here's an example (not in order):

```
//... earlier code omitted for brevity

var test = form.find('input').first().val();
alert(test); // <--- should return the value you want to post (2)

// ... (4) need to change 'Text' to 'model_description' to reflect your model
// properties (otherwise, how can your controller bind your model to the json object your submitting to it?)

var data = { model: [{ model_description: form.find('input').first().val(); }]};

// need to make data a JSON object (1a)

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //<-- specify POST (1b)
    dataType: "JSON", // <-- specify JSON (1c)
    url: '@Url.Action("createNewModel", "INV_Assets")', // <-- Easier way to do URL (3)
    data: jsonData, // JSON
    success: function(resp){ 
        //callback 
    },
    error: function() {
       //callback
   }
});
```

Now, with your **Controller...**

Toggle a breakpoint and make sure that your JSON object is binding to your model object:

```
public JsonResult createNewModel(INV_Models model)
{
    // jsonData.model_description should have automatically bound to 
    // model.model_description because the property names are the same
}
```

With regards to your `SaveChanges()` issue, this error is normally thrown when there's a type mismatch - or `null` data where required - you might want to wrap your db call in a `try-catch` then read/handle the error:

```
try 
{
   db.INV_Models.Add(model);
   db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
   // toggle breakpoint --> read error --> do something else? 
   // throw http error --> catch in ajax error callback?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying `wahwahwah`. Using your example I was able to make progress, but my controller action fails out at saving the changes to DB?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic - Ive updated my answer to include the EF SaveChanges() issue.

Comment: I've posted an EDIT2 above. Seems my new `Model` description is not being passed in/set when the save operation tries to execute?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic - it may be that your controller action is firing, but you are not passing any data in your `model.` You have to use exactly the same property naming conventions between your JSON and model objects, otherwise it won't bind... change `var data = { Text: ... ` to `var data = { model_description : ...` and make sure  `form.find('input').first().val() ` returns a value;

Comment: The following `var data = { model_description: form.find('input').first().val() };` ... `alert(data);` returns `[Object object]`?

Comment: is `form.find('input').first().val()' returning a value? Are you expecting this to be the value from your drop down? The rendered HTML from '@html.DropDownListFor` isn't an `input` -- please verify.

Comment: `alert(data.model_description.Text)` returns `undefined`...? If I'm understanding the code directly, I'm wanting `data` to contain the value from my input box (`name="model_description"`) in my form: `<form action="/createNewModel"><input type="text" name="model_description" /><input type="button" id="submitNewModel" value="Submit"></form>`

Comment: Ok - I think I see what's going on here. I will update my answer.

Comment: I have updated with my `EDIT3` above. For some reason, it seems that value in my `input` for the `model_description` is not being correctly retrieved and stored in my variable(s) for use in JSON...?

Comment: Hmm.... after playing with your fiddle I noticed my input form did not have the closing `/` for `<input type="button" id="submitNewModel" value="Submit" />` but I'm still getting garbage as far as the value which is getting stored within the variable.

Comment: I'm guessing it must be something with that `first()` selector. When I set the variable(s) as `document.getElementById('textNewModel').value` after adding the `ID` to the input `<input type="text" id="textNewModel" name="model_description" />`, the correct value is appearing in my variables/alerts. However, the value is NOT coming through as the `model.model_description` in my controller...?

Comment: Your JSON object needs to reflect the naming conventions of your controller parameter object... (and its properties.)  Your json object should look like this: `{ "model" : {[ "model_description" : "whatevertextyouarecapturing" ]}`